# DiskCache plugin strategy for e-mail images with tracking

Tags: c#, asp.net, imageresizer

Currently we're sending thousands of e-mails every day to our customers. An e-mail contains an image url with a specific Message ID. When the user downloads that image, I mark that message as opened in the database. For example:

```
http://cdn.mydomain.com/companylogos/{guid}.png?h=100&w=100&messageid=123
```

At this moment, every image request requires me to get the byte[ ] of the image from cache. Resize it. And Return it. This all takes place in a httphandler.

I would like to take the advantage of ImageResizer.net and the Disk Cache plugin. However, I still need to get the MessageId-querystring parameter. So I'm thinking about this solution.

**Extending HttpModule**

```
public class CustomInterceptModule : InterceptModule
{
    protected override void HandleRequest(HttpContext context, HttpModuleRequestAssistant ra, IVirtualFile vf)
    {
        var messageIdParam = context.Request.QueryString["messageId"];
        int messageId;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(messageIdParam) && int.TryParse(messageIdParam, out messageId))
        {
            // Do something with the ID here   
        }

        base.HandleRequest(context, ra, vf);
    }
}
```

Does this method still creates high performance, disk cached, results? Or am I interrupting this because I'm extending the HttpModule and I'm adding my own logic in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to increase performance and/or reduce the work you server needs to do, I would suggest that you should not use a full-size image for tracking purposes, but instead use an invisible 1x1.png image to track whether or not a message was opened, and simply use a standard img url that everybody shares (that can be distributed on a CDN and/or cached) for the image that people actually see.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I was also considering this option. But I've read that small (for example 1px images) might be blocked by spamfilters. Although companies like MailChimp also use this option. I'll discuss this with my collegues. If I got more questions, I'll post them here.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add an event handler to `ImageResizer.Config.Current.Pipeline.AuthorizeImage` - this will be called for all image requests, and is less brittle than subclassing the HttpModule.